# Workflow completed without executing all the tasks in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have following workflow, except the branching tasks all the other tasks are implemented using dummy operators.

But without completing descending tasks workflow is move to complete state.
[image: Graph view of the workflow]

[image: Tree view of the workflow]

Is there any particular reason(s) for not executing (skipping) descending tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason and the solution in the [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) using the triggering rules option. According to the documentation

> In the case of this DAG, join is downstream of follow_branch_a and branch_false. The join task will show up as skipped because its trigger_rule is set to all_success by default and skipped tasks will cascade through all_success.

So I have added `trigger_rule='none_failed'` to dss4_dummy, branch3 and end_routine tasks. Which gave me expected results as follows.

[image]